# PHP Html DOM parsing plain text

Tags: php, html, parsing, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I am trying to parse html file using simple html dom parser.Below is the html code. I want to get the plain text after p tag i.e. "Check out  www.freeportusa.com/packages-and-deals for the great offer from J.Crew for Men, Women & Children!". However i managed to get the promotion title i.e. "DEALS FROM J.CREW!". Any suggestion how to get that text after paragraph tag.

```
foreach($html->find('#sidebar h3') as $h3_cont)
    {
        if($h3_cont->next_sibling()->class == 'separator special')
        {
            $mem_det['promotions'] .= $h3_cont->next_sibling()->next_sibling()->innertext.'<br />';
            $mem_det['promotions_desc'] .= ??
        }
    }

<div id="sidebar">

    <h3 style="">PROMOTIONS</h3>
```

```
                <p><strong style="text-transform:uppercase">Deals from J.Crew!</strong></p>

                Check out  www.freeportusa.com/packages-and-deals for the great offer from J.Crew for Men, Women &amp; Children!  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get it because it's not an element. Your best bet is to get the parent div and strip out all the child elements.